# 401 error on Analytics API using public access api key

Tags: node.js, google-analytics-api

Not certain how to test this any other way, but using a public access api key results in a `Result: Login Required` error. Can Google Analytics not be called by a public access key?

```js
var google = require('googleapis')
var analytics = google.analytics('v3')
var c = require('./config.json')

analytics.data.ga.get({
    key: c.key,
    'ids': c.ids,
    'start-date': '2015-07-15',
    'end-date': '2015-07-24',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain if Google Analytics API supports calls using just a public_api key, so I was able to achieve access using a service account.

```js
var google = require('googleapis'),
    analytics = google.analytics({ version: 'v3'})
    key = require('./key.json'),

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'],
    null)

analytics.data.ga.get({
  'ids': 'ga:xxxxxxx',
  'start-date': startDate,
  'end-date': endDate,
  'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
  auth: jwtClient
  }, function (err, resp) {
    console.log(resp)
  })
```